# How to use register auth in laravel

Tags: php, laravel-6.2

Good day,
I'll need some assistance with my laravel application.
So i'm routing to a page with some data and I used the auth middleware and so before it routes to that page redirects to the login page if user is not logged in which is fine. After login it proceeds to the route specified. But now when I try to register instead it doesn't proceed to that route but only back to home page. Is there another middleware that handles that?
Here's my route.

```
Route::get('/myroute', 'MyController@method')->middleware('auth')->name('somename');
```

I'll appreciate your assistance.
Thanks

Comment: Yes, check RedirectIfAuthenticated.php middleware which apparently checks if users is authenticated and redirects them accordingly.

Comment: Look for `intended` redirect: https://pixelcave.com/blog/how-to-redirect-back-to-original-url-after-successful-login-in-laravel